# Does RGBDSLAM support ROS_MASTER_URI

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I enable roscore on a remote machine and suppose ROS_MASTER_URI will it do all the processing remotely?

My goal is to offload the loop closures onto a faster machine.

The longterm goal is to pick and choose what gets offloaded to ROS_MASTER_URI and what processes locally.

If you have information on any of these topics, your knowledge is greatly needed! Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228463/does-rgbdslam-support-ros_master_uri/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. All ROS nodes support ROS_MASTER_URI.

ROS nodes run on whichever machine you run them on (whereever you type `rosrun` or `roslaunch`). ROS will not move processes from one machine to another for you; you have to start them where you want them.

Have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines for more information.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-07**:
I've been tinkering quite a bit with that tutorial lately, which is what prompted my original post. It seems as though what I need to do is open up the rgbdslam src and send data to another machine where a node is running to receive and parse the data. Is that the route you would take?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-07**:
I haven't worked directly with rgbdslam, but it looks like is uses the openni_launch package for data capture, so the process for running the processing step on a separate machine should be as simple as running openni_launch on one machine, and rgbdslam on a different machine.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-07**:
The whole point of ROS is that you shouldn't have to modify the rgbdslam source code in order to have it pass ROS topic data over the network.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-07**:
That said, streaming full 3D point clouds over a network requires a lot of bandwidth.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-07**:
The [rgbdslam Usage with GUI](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam#USAGE_with_GUI) describes how to run the openni and rgbdslam nodes separately.